# java-script standards for write database property file?

Tags: javascript, database, properties

I want to know is there any standards for writing separate property file for database connection in java-script.such as url,db-name,login,password.
If yes,then how can we write property file and get these values from property file.

Comment: in [json](http://www.json.org/) files

Comment: But what about when the ip is changed all the time.we can do this also by using dotenv module.

Comment: if you can show what you have found so far from your own research then it'll be easier to help you - and the community will be more inclined to help with evidence of effort